# Using osm2pgsql data with pgrouting 2.0

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgsql, osm2pgrouting

I have successfully manage to make the workshop from of pgrouting (wrote for v1) with pgrouting v2. 
Now I want to use pgrouting 2 on my postgis database created with osm2pgsql.

The problem is first to create the segments and [this blog post](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2011/10/using-pgrouting-on-osm-database.html) was very helpfull for this.
However,I get:

```
gis=# select pgr_createTopology('network', 0.01, 'the_geom', 'gid');
ERROR:  We can not determine the srid of "network.the_geom"!
```

Is there a way to set the srid properly so that `pgr_createTopology` finds it.
Or is there an alternative way?
I can't believe osm2pgrouting is the only importer for pgrouting.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look in the "geometry_columns" table to see if there is a record for your table, that shows if there is the right SRID. There is a PostGIS function [`ST_SetSRID`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) to specify the SRID.

Second, I created a modified "osm2pgrouting" that should work with pgRouting 2.0. It's (same as pgRouting) in the [`develop` branch](https://github.com/pgrouting/osm2pgrouting/tree/develop) of its Github repository and will remain there until pgRouting 2.0 stable will be released.

I never tried osm2pgsql and later split the ways as described in the blog post, so I don't know how well this works. There is another tool named [`osm2po`](http://osm2po.de/), which can create you a valid road network for pgRouting.